# I created a query to select symptoms out of symptom table but I got semantical error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Here is my query:

```
$symptoms = $em->createQuery("SELECT p FROM QuestionnaireSigninBundle:TblSymptoms p where p.IsDeleted=0 ")->getArrayResult();
```

Here is the error message

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 62 near 'IsDeleted=0 ': Error: Class  
Questionnaire\SigninBundle\Entity\TblSymptoms has no field or association 
named IsDeleted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the message says your entity `TblSymptoms` has no field `IsDeleted`.

could be a type. in camelcase the field should be named `isDeleted`.

by the way, set the value direct in the query is a bad practice.

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT p FROM QuestionnaireSigninBundle:TblSymptoms p where p.isDeleted = ?1');
$query->setParameter(0);
```